# Maui Entry with keyboard = "Numeric" only accept numbers. Need a sequence of numbers

Tags: c#, behavior, maui, data-entry

I am making a MAUI app where I need the Entry class to accept a sequence of numbers like "10,30,222,33".
When setting Keyboard = "Numeric" the Entry class only accept entering a float like "-1.23". It seems that the Entry class have a built in behavior here.
I have tried to add my own behavior - but it does not overrule the built-in check.
Is there a way to overrule the built-in check in Entry when keyboard = "Numeric"?

Comment: What platform are you testing on? If its Android, AFAIK, the only solution is to create your own custom keyboard. The Android Entry with Numeric keyboard strongly assumes you are entering a single number. (This is an Android OS limitation, not a Maui limitation.) I don't know about other platforms. Google `xamarin forms custom keyboard` - should be similar on Maui.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thank you, Yes it is Android. So I have to fix it that way.